# Как использовать angular-translate и ng-repeat вместе?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-repeat

Пишу я на AngularJs.

Это пример с моего eng.json и объекты типа 1 работают нормально,но когда,я хочу использовать ng-repeat с массивом типа 2,я не знаю как сделать рабочий код

**1** `"brand": "TMComp"`

**2**

```
 "features" : [
       {"title" : "Start conversation"}
       {"title" : "Make a free call"},
       {"title" : "Take a picture"},
       {"title" : "Send your video"}
     ]
```

**HTML**

**1.** `<h3> {{'brand' | translate}}</h3>` - работает

**2.** Вот как раз как мне использовать ng-repeat вместе с angular-translate

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как-то так

```
<h3> ng-repeat="(key,val) in features">{{val}} </h3>
```

Comment: Печально,но не работает.Ну мне в этом коде кроме того,что вы h3 закрили не там,менять же не надо ничего?

Comment: А что-то в консоле браузера написано ) ?

Comment: Ничего)))У меня и джсон немного другой,но это ничего не меняет,вот что в коде типо <!--  ngRepeat: (key,val) in pages.home.features -->,но ошибок нету )))